# Convert unix time to readable date in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, unix-timestamp, dataframe

I have a dataframe with unix times and prices in it. I want to convert the index column so that it shows in human readable dates.

So for instance I have `date` as `1349633705` in the index column but I'd want it to show as `10/07/2012` (or at least `10/07/2012 18:15`).

For some context, here is the code I'm working with and what I've tried already:

```
import json
import urllib2
from datetime import datetime
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://blockchain.info/charts/market-price?&format=json')
data = json.load(response)   
df = DataFrame(data['values'])
df.columns = ["date","price"]
#convert dates 
df.date = df.date.apply(lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d"))
df.index = df.date
```

As you can see I'm using
`df.date = df.date.apply(lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d"))` here which doesn't work since I'm working with integers, not strings. I think I need to use `datetime.date.fromtimestamp` but I'm not quite sure how to apply this to the whole of `df.date`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 384, accepted):

These appear to be seconds since epoch.

```
In [20]: df = DataFrame(data['values'])

In [21]: df.columns = ["date","price"]

In [22]: df
Out[22]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 358 entries, 0 to 357
Data columns (total 2 columns):
date     358  non-null values
price    358  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1)

In [23]: df.head()
Out[23]: 
         date  price
0  1349720105  12.08
1  1349806505  12.35
2  1349892905  12.15
3  1349979305  12.19
4  1350065705  12.15
In [25]: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],unit='s')

In [26]: df.head()
Out[26]: 
                 date  price
0 2012-10-08 18:15:05  12.08
1 2012-10-09 18:15:05  12.35
2 2012-10-10 18:15:05  12.15
3 2012-10-11 18:15:05  12.19
4 2012-10-12 18:15:05  12.15

In [27]: df.dtypes
Out[27]: 
date     datetime64[ns]
price           float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 109):

If you try using:

```
df[DATE_FIELD]=(pd.to_datetime(df[DATE_FIELD],***unit='s'***))
```

and receive an error :

> "pandas.tslib.OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input with unit 's'"

This means the `DATE_FIELD` is not specified in seconds.

In my case, it was milli seconds - `EPOCH time`.

The conversion worked using below:

```
df[DATE_FIELD]=(pd.to_datetime(df[DATE_FIELD],unit='ms'))
```

Answer (score 42):

Assuming we imported `pandas as pd` and `df` is our dataframe

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='s')
```

works for me.

Answer (score 18):

The Pandas Documentation gives this and other format examples and wasn't included in any of the above previous answers. Link:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

**Code**

```
pd.to_datetime(1490195805, unit='s')
```

Timestamp('2017-03-22 15:16:45')

```
pd.to_datetime(1490195805433502912, unit='ns')
```

Timestamp('2017-03-22 15:16:45.433502912')

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, by changing a line of the above code:

```
# df.date = df.date.apply(lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d"))
df.date = df.date.apply(lambda d: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

It should also work.