# Matplotlib: Display epoch timestamp as regular date in a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, timestamp

Here is my code to plot col_A vs. time:

```
ax[0].plot(data_df['time'], data_df['col_A'] , color = 'black')
```

The the plot looks like this:

[image]

The x-axis `time` is currently in "epoch timestamp" unit (https://www.freeformatter.com/epoch-timestamp-to-date-converter.html). Can I display the x-axis using the regular date in the plot? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just either convert the timestamp before plotting or create a new column in the format you want? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231871/convert-unix-time-to-readable-date-in-pandas-dataframe) for example. There's plenty of examples on Google.

Comment: Does it work if you add `data_df['time'].astype('datetime64[s]')` instead of only `data_df['time']` inside `plot` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding `data_df['time'].astype('datetime64[s]')` instead of only `data_df['time']` inside plot function:

```
ax[0].plot(data_df['time'].astype('datetime64[s]'), data_df['col_A'] , color = 'black')
```