# Convert epoch time to formatted date string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime, timestamp

I have a DataFrame with epoch timestamp and I want to create a new column with a formatted date string.

```
index   timestamp
0       1456407930
1       1456407945
2       1456407961
3       1456407977
4       1456407992
5       1456408008
6       1456408024
7       1456408040
8       1456408055
9       1456408071
10      1456408087
11      1456408102
```

First, I successfully convert the timestamp to datetime format using

```
data['date_num'] = mdate.epoch2num(data['timestamp'])
```

But I didn't find a function to get a new column with a string formatted date `(such as “%Y-%m-%d”)`.

I would appreciate any ideas?
Patricio

Comment: `df.timestamp=pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp,unit='s').dt.date
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231871/convert-unix-time-to-readable-date-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 7):

Specify `unit='s'` with [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html). Then use [`pd.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html).

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='s')\
               .dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(df)

    index   timestamp        date
0       0  1456407930  2016-02-25
1       1  1456407945  2016-02-25
2       2  1456407961  2016-02-25
3       3  1456407977  2016-02-25
4       4  1456407992  2016-02-25
5       5  1456408008  2016-02-25
6       6  1456408024  2016-02-25
7       7  1456408040  2016-02-25
8       8  1456408055  2016-02-25
9       9  1456408071  2016-02-25
10     10  1456408087  2016-02-25
11     11  1456408102  2016-02-25
```

Comment: Simple, beatiful solution and upvote. I know the feeling when write a correct answer and nobody upvote it in order to recognize the invested time and effort into answering it.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut, Thks, yours is acceptable too :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` method by passing a `lambda` expression as argument.

```
df['new_column'] = df['timestamp'].map(lambda val: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(val).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Output

```
    timestamp  new_column
0  1456407930  2016-02-25
1  1456407945  2016-02-25
-------------------------
```