# How to resolve TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>

Tags: python, pandas, epoch

Epoch value of time is converted as follows for a particular epoch value:

```
time.strftime("%H:%M:%S ", time.localtime(28000000000))  
Out[82]: '07:16:40 '
```

But when I apply the above method to a column of epoch time in the dataset,

```
time.strftime("%H:%M:%S ", time.localtime(df1['d']))
```

I am getting following error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to type 'float'
```

Where I am going wrong?

`df1['d']` is epoch time duration which have data as follows in the column:

```
28000000000
16000000000
33000000000
28000000000
27000000000
22000000000
26000000000
22000000000
22000000000
22000000000
46000000000
```

I need the epoch time not the `datetime` object format.

Comment: what is the value of time.localtime(df1['d']) ?

Comment: Hello @sachindubey value of  `time.localtime(df1['d'])` gives `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>`

Comment: sorry i mean value of df1['d'] ?

Comment: df1['d'] have epoch time durations in a column like 
28000000000
16000000000
33000000000
28000000000
27000000000
22000000000
26000000000
22000000000
22000000000
22000000000
46000000000

I will add these value in main section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert unix time to readable date in pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231871/convert-unix-time-to-readable-date-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: my question is regarding time duration in epoch whereas the link you have shared is regarding `datetime` objects @Georgy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with lambda function:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'d':[28000000000,28000000000]})

df1['times'] = df1['d'].apply(lambda x: time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime(x)))
```

Or `list comprehension`:

```
df1['times'] = [time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime(x)) for x in df1['d']]

print (df1)
             d     times
0  28000000000  03:46:40
1  28000000000  03:46:40
```

Comment: Yes, both of the above methods works. Thanks.
One doubt  what if multiple columns are needed to transform this way , is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible,`cols = ['d','d1','d2']` and then `df1[cols] = df1[cols].applymap(lambda x: time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime(x)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` function.

```
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.DataFrame([[28000000000, 2.5], [28100000000, 2.54]], columns=['d', 'e'])

df['time'] = df.d.map(lambda t: time.strftime("%H:%M:%S ", time.localtime(t)))
print(df)
#              d     e       time
# 0  28000000000  2.50  03:46:40 
# 1  28100000000  2.54  13:33:20
```