# Pandas error on unix datetime conversation -- OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input with unit 's'

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting this error

```
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 356, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_with_unit_to_datetime
pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input with unit 's'
```

when trying to convert pandas column to datetime format.

I checked this answer [Convert unix time to readable date in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231871/convert-unix-time-to-readable-date-in-pandas-dataframe/19231939)

but it did not help me to solve the problem.

There is an issue on github that seems to be closed but in the same time people keep reporting issues:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10987

Dataframe column has unix time format, here is print out of top 20 rows

```
0      1420096800
1      1420096800
2      1420097100
3      1420097100
4      1420097400
5      1420097400
6      1420093800
7      1420097700
8      1420097700
9      1420098000
10     1420098480
11     1420098600
12     1420099200
13     1420099500
14     1420099500
15     1420100100
16     1420100400
17     1420096800
18     1420100700
19     1420100820
20     1420101840
```

Any ideas about how I might solve it?

I tried changing units from `s` to `ms`, but it did not help.

```
pd.__version__
'0.24.2'
```

Row

```
df[key] = pd.to_datetime(df[key], unit='s')
```

Comment: May we know which row raise the issue ?

Comment: @WeNYoBen oops sorry updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if you add the `origin='unix'` parameter:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], origin='unix', unit='s')

0    2015-01-01 07:20:00
1    2015-01-01 07:20:00
2    2015-01-01 07:25:00
3    2015-01-01 07:25:00
4    2015-01-01 07:30:00
```