# UNIX conversion to datetime either mismatch or returns 1970-01-01

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert a Pandas DataFrame column from UNIX to Datetime, but I either get a mismatch error or the new dates are all 1970-01-01.

Here is tail sample of the list:

> ds             y
>
> 86  1625616000000  34149.989815
>
> 87  1625702400000  33932.254638
>
> 88  1625788800000  32933.578199
>
> 89  1625875200000  33971.297750
>
> 90  1625884385000  33868.766626

When I look at how my UNIX looks like in datetime:

```
mydatetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(1618185600000 // 1000, tz=tzutc())
print('mydatetime',mydatetime)
```

I get:

> mydatetime 2021-04-12 00:00:00+00:00

So when I use the conversion function:

```
df2 = pd.to_datetime(df1['ds'].astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+%f:%Z')
```

I get:

> ValueError: time data '1618185600000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d
> %H:%M:%S+%f:%Z' (match)

But, when I use the lazy road:

```
df2 = pd.to_datetime(df1['ds'], unit='ns')
```

The results are:

> 86 1970-01-01 00:27:05.616000
>
> 87 1970-01-01 00:27:05.702400
>
> 88 1970-01-01 00:27:05.788800
>
> 89 1970-01-01 00:27:05.875200
>
> 90 1970-01-01 00:27:05.886197
>
> Name: ds, type: datetime64[ns]

Comment: Did you consider: `unit='ms'`? This converts to seconds: `1618185600000 // 1000` and gives you the correct answer with `fromtimestamp`, which suggests you are starting with milliseconds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert unix time to readable date in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231871/convert-unix-time-to-readable-date-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.Timestamp` to convert to datetime:

```
>>> df['ds'].mul(1e6).apply(pd.Timestamp)

0   2021-07-07 00:00:00
1   2021-07-08 00:00:00
2   2021-07-09 00:00:00
3   2021-07-10 00:00:00
4   2021-07-10 02:33:05
Name: ds, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or suggested by @HenryEcker:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['ds'], unit='ms')

0   2021-07-07 00:00:00
1   2021-07-08 00:00:00
2   2021-07-09 00:00:00
3   2021-07-10 00:00:00
4   2021-07-10 02:33:05
Name: ds, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: FWIW `pd.to_datetime(df['ds'], unit='ms')` gives the same output.

Comment: @HenryEcker , you're right, I just did try it and it returns the same results as well.

Comment: It's actually [an answer from the duplicate I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44976944/15497888)