# python pandas converting UTC integer to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, api, datetime, utc

I am calling some financial data from an API which is storing the time values as (I think) UTC (example below):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdQf4.png)

I cannot seem to convert the entire column into a useable date, I can do it for a single value using the following code so I know this works, but I have 1000's of rows with this problem and thought pandas would offer an easier way to update all the values.

```
from datetime import datetime
tx = int('1645804609719')/1000
print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(tx).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: UTC is a timezone, not a storage format. There's no UTC integer. `1645804609719` is most likely a Unix timestamp. What's the expected date ?

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, thanks for the quick reply! so using the latest entry in the output and the code above ```tx = int('1646044696278')/1000 ```  I get: 2022-02-28 10:38:16.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert unix time to readable date in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231871/convert-unix-time-to-readable-date-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: You can use `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],unit='ms')` to convert the millisecond-based Unix timestamp to a datetime64

Comment: This worked thank you for such a quick reply. I was going nuts as newbie to coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **"to_numeric"** to convert the column in integers, **"div"** to divide it by 1000 and finally a loop to iterate the dataframe column with **datetime** to get the format you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['1584199972000', '1645804609719'], 'values': [30,40]})
df['date'] = pd.to_numeric(df['date']).div(1000)
for i in range(len(df)):
    df.iloc[i,0] = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(df.iloc[i,0]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                  date  values
0  2020-03-14 15:32:52      30
1  2022-02-25 15:56:49      40
```

Comment: Hi Edoardo, thanks for this, however it converts the time column to 1970, which is one of many problem I was facing when first trying to solve this:  ```1970-01-01 00:27:26.070645411```

Comment: Hi Cunnial, I updated the code. I think for this format you must iterate with a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['date'] = df.date.apply(lambda x: datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(x)/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Another way to do it is by using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) as recommended by Panagiotos in the comments:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],unit='ms')
```